# Trying to understand why I'm getting "Rendered more hooks than previous render"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on adding a select box for my React Native component, but I keep getting the mentioned error message and I'm not sure why.  Any help is appreciated.

Error message: Rendered more hooks than previous render

> 9: useState useState
> 10: useState useState
> 11: useState useState
> 12: undefined useEffect

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';

const GET_CIGARS = gql`
  query getCigars {
    cigars {
      brand,
      name
    }
  }
`;

function AddFaveCigar() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CIGARS);
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState("");
  const [brandArr, setBrandArr] = useState([]);
  const [cigarNameArr, setCigarNameArr] = useState([]);

  if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error: {error.message}</Text>;

  function addFavorite(e) {

  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const filterByBrand = data.cigars.filter((objArr, index, arr) => index === arr.findIndex(obj => (obj.brand === objArr.brand)));
    let brandsArr = [];
    filterByBrand.forEach((cigar, index) => {
      brandsArr.push({ label: cigar.brand, value: cigar.brand, key: index })
    });
    setBrandArr(brandsArr);
  }, []);

  function fillCigarName(brand) {
    const filterCigarByBrand = data.cigars.filter(objArr => (brand === objArr.brand));
    let cigarArr = [];
    filterCigarByBrand.forEach((cigar, index) => {
      cigarArr.push({ label: cigar.name, value: cigar.name, key: index })
    });
    setCigarNameArr(cigarArr);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!loading && !error && (
        <View style={styles.faveContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.faveTitle}>New Favorite</Text>
          <Text style={styles.inputName}>Cigar Brand</Text>
          <View style={styles.inputBox}>
            <InputLabel id="select-brand" >Select brand</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="select-brand"
              id="select-brand"
              value={brand}
              label="Select brand"
              onChange={fillCigarName}
            >
              {brandArr.map(brand => (
                <MenuItem value={brand.brand}>{brand.brand}</MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
            {/* <RNPickerSelect
              placeholder={{ label: "Select brand", value: null }}
              items={brandArr}
              onValueChange={
                (value) => {
                  fillCigarName(value)
                  setBrand(value)
                }
              }
            /> */}
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.inputName}>Cigar Name</Text>
          <View style={styles.inputBox}>
            {/* <RNPickerSelect
              placeholder={{ label: "Select name", value: null }}
              items={cigarNameArr}
              onValueChange={(value) => setCigarNameArr(value)}
            /> */}
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.inputName}>Size</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} placeholder="size" />
          {/* <Pressable style={[styles.btnContainer, styles.boxShadow]} onPress={(e) => addFavorite(e)}>
            <View style={styles.btnIconContainer}>
              Add Favorite
            </View>
          </Pressable> */}
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default AddFaveCigar;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  faveContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '5%',
    left: 10,
    width: '95%', 
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
  },
  faveTitle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 15
  },
  inputName: {
    paddingBottom: 5
  },
  inputBox: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  pickerStyle: {
    border: 0,
  },
  pickerItem: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  }
});
```

Comment: @Abe I understand the meaning, but I'm not fully understanding where that's happening on my app...?

Comment: Your useEffect is written after two return statements. You can't return before invoking a hook.